# Why does $emit not work in my vue component

Tags: vuejs2

I've been banging my head against this problem for hours. I can't see a problem and from what I can tell I am following the documentation here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

code below

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <test-listen>
    <test-emit></test-emit>
  </test-listen>
</div>
<script>
Vue.component('test-listen', {
  data: function(){
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    customHandler : function(e){
      console.log(e);
      console.log("works");
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class='test_listen' v-on:custom="customHandler">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('test-emit',{
  data: function(){
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler : function(){
      this.$emit('custom');
    }
  },
  template : `
    <div class='test_emit' v-on:click="clickHandler">
      test
    </div>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el:"#wrap"
});
</script>
<style>
.test_listen{
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.test_emit{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#f0f;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:20px;
}
</style>
```

But the listeners are definitely bound to the element, because if I dispatch a vanillaJS CustomEvent it triggers the console log just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong here.

1. Vue events can be bound to components only I guess (talking vue events here)
2. Slots are not good with events.  ([Source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4332#issuecomment-263444492) - Evan You, Vue author)

**If you really want to pass data here and there without restriction better to use `Global Event Bus Approach`**

> **Working example of your code with some minor correction.**

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <test-listen>
  </test-listen>
</div>
<script>
Vue.component('test-listen', {
  data: function(){
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    customHandler : function(e){
      console.log(e);
      console.log("works");
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div class='test_listen' >
      <test-emit v-on:custom="customHandler"></test-emit>
    </div>
  `
});

Vue.component('test-emit',{
  data: function(){
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    clickHandler : function(e){
      // e => event : didnt pass here as console will stuck so
      this.$emit('custom', 'somedata');
    }
  },
  template : `
    <div class='test_emit' v-on:click="clickHandler">
      test
    </div>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el:"#wrap"
});
</script>
<style>
.test_listen{
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.test_emit{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:#f0f;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm kinda disappointed because I really want the slots for composability so I guess I'll take a look at the Global Event Bus Approach.

Comment: Yes sure Use Slots.. but for event use `Global Event Bus` that is quite popular and effective approach.

Answer (score 13):

I see only one mistake here. You should add `v-on` to the child component.
When you `$emit('custom')` from inside it will call "customHandler" on the parent component.

[Working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txf1kfx9/)

```vue
<test-listen>
    <test-emit v-on:custom="customHandler"></test-emit>
</test-listen>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! This definitely works.

Answer (score 2):

With `this.$emit()` is a way to say to the parent component that *hey i created an event and now you can listen on this event*

You are doing well but you don't listen in parent component the event emitted by child. [I made it to work.Click here to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/zyf5nzvd/)

So in order to make your code to work,In test-listen component,use as child the test-emit component.

Then inside the div `#wrap` use the test-listen component

Your problem was that you did't listen to the event in parent component.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :-). It is correct and I would select it but I can only do one and I want the github issue link and the global message bus suggestion for future readers.

Comment: What is parent in this case? On every example,e they mention parent and yet they proceed to handle the event on the same component, which in my case does not work also. It's confusing.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 parent is the component that uses the component that emits the event. So if the component is called MyComponent then every component that uses that component is a parent of that

Comment: @Roland I'm new to vue so my guess is because I'm using Vue 3, I had to declare the event in `emits` in order for the event to be fired and caught. If i don't declare it, it doesn't work. Also, i'm using vue without a build system